# How to use log4j in an EJB Module with WebLogic?

Tags: netbeans, log4j, ejb, jms

I have included the log4j.jar in libraries;
added log4j.xml in the sources folder;
but I m getting an error:

```
**<Apr 22, 2014 11:07:50 AM PKT> <Warning> <EJB> <BEA-010065> <MessageDrivenBean threw an Exception in onMessage(). The exception is:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
at test.MyMessageBean.onMessage(MyMessageBean.java:39)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:575)
at     weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:477)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:375)
at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:4855)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace**
```

I have also tried including classpath: .\lib\log4j...**.jar** in the MANIFEST.MF
but still no positive response..

Kindly guide  me how to resolve this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it's EJB Module or you are working on some other application with WebLogic Server;
it requires a configuration Process;  you can go through the links given below:

[[http://techworldrocks.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/configure-log4j-logging-for-weblogic-server-log/][1]](http://techworldrocks.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/configure-log4j-logging-for-weblogic-server-log/%5d%5b1%5d)

[[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24428/config_logs.htm#i1014785][1]](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24428/config_logs.htm#i1014785%5d%5b1%5d)

Answer (score 1):

Use Java Util Logging, which is included in the JEE spec. No additional jars have to be added.

Comment: Thank you Sir; I forgot to mention "WebLogic" which was a problem in itself and needed a complete configuration process;
Alhamdulillah I am done with it.
Thank you for the Response. JazakALLAH Khair